# Which one would you use "the", "that" or "this"? About English Anaphora

Tags: french

I read a book about French anaphora.
In French, there is a distinction between the definite article "le" and the demonstrative "ce", and I wonder if the same usage also applies to English.
Which word would native English speakers choose in the example sentences below?

John is talking to his wife about a woman he saw at a cafe yesterday.
John: "A woman entered the cafe and sat at the back of the room."
a. "I had already seen **the/that/this** woman near my house a few days ago."
b. "In fact, **the/that/this** woman always orders lemonade."
c. "I don't like **the/that/this** woman very much, because she is too talkative."

The book says, in the same cases above, French people use "ce" instead of "le".
I don't think it's true of English, but I'm not sure as I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: All of them are natural and grammatical. There are slight connotation differences, but it's hard to explain, haha. The difference between this vs that is most apparent when there are two things being compared

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about the grammar and a usage of a specific language (English) and instead belongs in either the English or ELL sites.

Comment: @Tristan It's not about grammar really. It's about deixis, which can be linguistics.

Comment: @Lambie it's specifically about the usage _in English_

Comment: @Tristan So, if it is about Hindi, Telugu, German and I-dunno-what-all, it's okay? Tons of linguistics questions on this site are about English. For me, this would just be one more., I consider that it goes beyond the purview of simple grammar. Deixis and performatives. Though not performative here.

Comment: @Lambie no. The fact it's about the usage in a specific language is the issue. The fact that language happens to be English just means there are two better-suited sites

Comment: @Tristan https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/search?q=deixis

Comment: @Lambie those questions are asking linguistic questions about deixis, not about the use of deixis in a specific language

Comment: @Tristan Last comment from me: You can't explain deixis in the void. You have to do it in a language and for a language. Goodness. And many of them use English to do that. Sure. That does not a make this a non-linguistics question.

Comment: @Lambie of course, but this is asking about the use of deixis in a _single_ language. Additionally it is asking purely about which choice speakers would make. It is clearly asking about the grammar of language, and not merely using English to illustrate a more general question about deixis. It is a question of English grammar not of linguisitcs and belongs on either the English or ELL sites

Comment: @Tristan You want to win? You can win. Often, OPs don't understand the full scope of or lack of scope in their questions...